# If you throw additional compute at DQN will you get the same results as if you threw compute at transformers?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, training, transformer

Recent performance in transformer based AI models have done really well by just throwing additional compute and data into the training. Can you expect similar levels of results by throwing more simulations at a Deep Q learning agent?

Comment: one is an algorithm, the other one an architecture